# Проблема с текстом установки

Tags: python, download

Я с использованием вашего простого примера сделал скрипт, в котором после установки происходит распаковка и удаление файла. Следующий вопрос, как можно добавить к установщику скрипт, чтобы при нажатии кнопки в начале писало "Установка начата" , потом текст исчезает и появляется другой например "Распаковка архива", а в конце скрипта "Архив установлен". Вот скрипт:

```
def download_file(url: str, file_name: str):

    try:

        local_file_name, _ = urlretrieve(url, file_name)
        print(os.path.abspath(local_file_name))
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())

    import zipfile

    fantasy_zip = zipfile.ZipFile('sborka.zip')
    fantasy_zip.extractall()

    fantasy_zip.close()
    import os


    path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'sborka.zip')
    os.remove(path)


... 


def downloadevent(self):
    url = 'http://ssilka/sborka.zip'
    file_name = 'sborka.zip'

    thread = Thread(target=download_file, args=(url, file_name))
    thread.start()
```

Comment: Качать нужно в отдельном потоке, чтобы не останавливать главный поток, в котором работает GUI, тогда и не будет виснуть окно

Comment: @gil9red Можешь привести пример на коде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример скачивания файла в отдельном потоке:

```
from threading import Thread
import traceback
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

def download_file(url: str, file_name: str):
    try:
        urlretrieve(url, file_name)
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())

url = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5ed9664c5a688eb0355acb782a94f0d5?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1'
file_name = 'img.png'

thread = Thread(target=download_file, args=(url, file_name))
thread.start()
```

---

```
from threading import Thread
import traceback
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import sys

def download_file(url: str, file_name: str):
    try:
        urlretrieve(url, file_name)
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())

...

class Ui_Form:
...
    def SetupUi(self):
        ...
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.WebDownload)

    def WebDownload(self):
        myUrl = "http://1//2.zip"
        myFile = "3.zip"

        thread = Thread(target=download_file, args=(myUrl, myFile))
        thread.start()
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Сейчас проверю.

Comment: @gli9red ошибку выкидывает. Точно у вас всё правильно написано? Я только вместо url свой написал и file_name свой.

Comment: @Сергей, пример в ответе рабочий, не пробовали запускать? Всегда пишите про ошибки, а то то, что у вас ошибка ничего не говорит, да и нет одной ошибки на всё :)

Comment: Сейчас в отдельном файле попробую. Просто мне нужно, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку качался файл.

Comment: Странно, но когда привязка к кнопке тонна разных ошибок, а когда через пустой файл их 0.

Comment: А скиньте пример вашего кода и те ошибки

Comment: Сейчас изменю вопрос.

Comment: Я доделал. Сначала код, потом ошибка.

Comment: @Сергей, неудивительно, что у вас ошибка. Во-первый, `download_file` это не метод, а фунция, поэтому по `self.` к нему не обратиться, во-вторых, его лучше не использовать как коннект к сигналу, т.е. в эту функцию еще и параметры нужно передавать. Обновлю ответ

Comment: @Сергей, кст, я думал, что вы tk используете, но раз это qt, но можно и на `QThread` переписать, например, если понадобится дополнительная функциональность через сигналы, типа передачи прогресса скачивания или имени файла. Но, в принципе, это можно сделать вручную через callback функции, но мне кажется, что через сигналы будет лучше

Comment: Кстати вы мне очень нужны. Я никак не могу сделать прогресс бар к установке . Так что можете написать код, чтобы была последующая возможность написания прогресс бара?

Comment: @Сергей, если разобрались с ошибкой, то прошу проголосовать и отметить ответ :) А по поводу прогресс бара это уже отдельный вопрос, я могу подсказать как это для urlretrieve делать: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/4692cbb36b5addb0f2bd5e93e69eb8c7c257bdf8/download_file/with_progress.py#L54 если не сможете приспособить, то создавайте новый вопрос с [минимальным, самодостаточным и воспроизводимым примером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) :)

Comment: Извините, ваш скрипт снова не сработал. Пишет ошибку, что имя download_file не найдено... Про прогресс бар я напишу.

Comment: @Сергей, поместите функцию в начало файла, выше класса, убедитесь что правильно называется функция -- мало ли опечатались

Comment: Теперь ошибок нет, но файл не качается.

Comment: @Сергей, в `download_file` в `except` что-то есть? мб там ошибка была, а вы ее не выводили? Обновил ответ, добавил обработку исключения: `print(traceback.format_exc())`

Comment: Я пробовал уже.

Comment: @Сергей, добавьте `reporthook` из https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/4692cbb36b5addb0f2bd5e93e69eb8c7c257bdf8/download_file/with_progress.py#L54, возможно он таки качает файл

Comment: Ладно, спасибо в любом случае.

Comment: @Сергей, ок, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :) Но я могу посмотреть код, если приложите. Не обязательно в вопрос, можно ссылку с проблемным кодом на https://gist.github.com или на подобный сервис

Comment: Да, это у вас ошибка в коде. Мне ошибку не выдаёт, но файл не качает.
Посмотрите у себя, проверьте.

Comment: @Сергей, и какая у меня ошибка? Мой код успешно скачал картинку по ссылке, второй -- это пример адаптации для вашего кода и он по факту сам по себе не рабочий -- я показал как метод WebDownload нужно подсоединить к сигналу и что в методе вызывать. Очевидно, что проблема у вас в коде, предоставьте его, чтобы мог помочь

Comment: Я по такому же принципу не могу скачать архив.

Comment: Картинку завтра попробую

Comment: Всё равно не работает, кстати прогресс бар нужен не консольный, а чтобы в файле показывался.

Comment: @Сергей, нет разницы архив там или нет, все-равно файлы и оно качает файлы. Ну, ок, сделаю на pyqt5 пример, что по кнопке скачает архивю Насчет прогресс бара, я не буду в этом теме вам больше помогать -- сделайте отдельный вопрос, там и опишите что нужно, включая то, что уже есть (я про код)

Comment: @Сергей, сделал простой пример https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/caec1446f45818a44d790d08e52ea6722e4f7548/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/download_file/simple.py#L40 т.к. у файла не указан полный путь, то он будет скачан в **активную директорию**

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас посмотрю. А вы не знаете, как сделать, чтобы файл устанавливался в относительную директорию? Я уже 2-ой день решение найти не могу.

Comment: @Сергей, не использовать полный путь, ваш `"3.zip"` уже относительный путь, т.е. файл попадет в текущую активную директорию, если нужно, например в папку выше поместить, то: `"../3.zip"`. Если не уверены в правильности указания относительного пути, то приводите его к абсолютному `os.path.abspath` и проверяйте что он совпадает с предполагаемым. Кст, если любопытно, то есть еще пример скачивания, но через QThread https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/50d79a4bedbdfa4f165c05a8578ba944c0d8b565/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/download_file/complex.py#L15 он сложнее, но лучше

Comment: Я с использованием вашего простого примера сделал скрипт, в котором после установки происходит распаковка и удаление файла. Следующий вопрос, как можно добавить к установщику скрипт, чтобы при нажатии кнопки в начале писало "Установка начата" , потом текст исчезает и появляется другой например "Распаковка архива", а в конце скрипта "Архив установлен". Сейчас в вопросе код распишу.

Comment: Сможете помочь?

Comment: @Сергей, если мой ответ помог, отметьте его